# Delete @deprecated apex class

Tags: apex, class, deprecated

how can I delete deprecated class? In list of apex classes I don't see button to delete @deprecated class [image]. I'm also not able to remove @deprecated attribute because this class was included in released package.

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 4):

You can not delete components that have been released in a managed package, by default. Regardless of whether they are deprecated or not. You can log a case at Salesforce support to request the "Delete managed components" feature. After activation of this feature, you will be able to delete the apex class. There are some risks involved though, so use the feature with care.