# Cannot delete @Deprecated component in a managed package even with SF deletion tool

Tags: apex, managed-package, class, deprecation

We have a @deprecated apex class in our managed package and want to delete it. We logged a case to enable the Component Deletion Tool but still cannot delete the @deprecated component. Here's what I see:

[image]

[This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190910/delete-deprecated-apex-class) Suggests I should be able to delete but I cannot. How can I do this?

Comment: A colleague mentioned he couldn't delete when Lightning Experience was selected but could when Classic is selected.

Comment: This is in Classic Experience. I'll try Lightning to see if there is a difference.

Comment: Is the deprecated class still referenced by any other metadata?

Comment: Good point @DanielBallinger! I don't see it being used by any Apex classes or Visualforce pages or components. Not sure what else could be blocking deletion.

Comment: I used the link below to confirm it is not used anywhere
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8437/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-where-a-class-is-used-other-than-attempting-to-delet

Comment: Does it contain anything marked `global`?

Comment: Yeah it was a global rest end point

Answer (score 0):

We cannot remove Deprecated class from a managed package.

For more information, go through this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_deprecated.htm

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! It's generally better if you can take the information from the link and reproduce the important parts here. Links have a tendency to go dead over time. Reproducing the information here helps mitigate the issue when the link does go dead (and not having to follow links to get a complete answer is nicer than having to follow links).